# Access to files is denied while the file is being moved Android 10

Tags: java, android, android-10.0

I need to rename a file, I use the Files.move method. But nothing happens. Please wait to solve this problem. I am testing on an emulator with Android 10. Below are the permissions, error, and implementation of the move.

Permissions :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    tools:ignore="ScopedStorage" />
```

```
android:requestRawExternalStorageAccess="true"
android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
```

```
val src = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    Paths.get(songItem.realUri)
} else {
    TODO("VERSION.SDK_INT < O")
}
val dest = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    Paths.get("$parent/$newName")
} else {
    TODO("VERSION.SDK_INT < O")
}
try {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        Files.move(src, dest) //Error
    }
    println("Renaming succeeded")
} catch (e: IOException) {
    e.printStackTrace()
}
```

`W/System.err: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /storage/emulated/0/Music/02. Alex Skrindo - Jumbo.mp3 -> /storage/emulated/0/Music/krindo - Jumbo.mp3 W/System.err:     at sun.nio.fs.UnixCopyFile.move(UnixCopyFile.java:457) W/System.err:     at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.move(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:262) W/System.err:     at java.nio.file.Files.move(Files.java:1395)`

Comment: Please give full paths of src and dest.

Comment: This is the full path -  /storage/emulated/0/Music/02. Alex Skrindo - Jumbo.mp3? If not, please write how to set it correctly.

Comment: That is only one path. I asked for two: src and dest.

Comment: src: /storage/emulated/0/Music/02. Alex Skrindo - Jumbo.mp3; dest: /storage/emulated/0/Music/krindo - Jumbo.mp3

Comment: Try File.exists() and File.canWrite() on src before the move.

Comment: src.exists() - true; src.isWritable() - false

Comment: Well if it is not writable you cannot move it. Also you cannot delete it. If File.canRead() returns true you could make a copy if the destination directory is writable.

Comment: In general, I just need to rename it, but how to do it specifically on Android 10?

Answer (score 0):

Here I wrote another file renaming solution, but in Android 10 nothing happens, although in 11 and above it renames normally.

```
public class PathDiv {
public static String dev(String path){
    return path.replaceAll("^(.*)/.*?$","$1");
}

public static void renameFilesInDir(String path, String dirIn, String ext) {

    File checkFile = new File(path);
        if (checkFile.isFile()) {
            try {
                checkFile.renameTo(new File(dirIn, ext));

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
}
```

}
path: /storage/emulated/0/Music/04. Kasger - Highland.mp3
dirIn: /storage/emulated/0/Music
ext: Highland.mp3

```
PathDiv.renameFilesInDir(songItem.realUri,PathDiv.dev(songItem.realUri),newName.toString())
```

Please help, what is the problem?

Comment: are you using the permission in the manifest?

Comment: Yes of course: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"